# Create manager class or wrap class

Tags: java, oop

I have a config class from an API I am using which contains methods to get/set values in the config. The config does not have any methods or a constructor that loads it from a file, is it better to wrap the config so that it has a method or constructor to load it from a file or to create a manager class which returns a config instance?

Comment: "Better" is a very subjective characteristic. It sounds like you have certain pros and cons for each approach in mind already. Why don't you share them, and we can help you evaluate the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your config class is a pure model. Wrapping it up and you want to change the functionality of a "config". This is not your intent? You don't want the "config" to "function" in a different way?

I/O work in constructors is bad, can you tell why? Well, you can put the I/O work in the methods of the wrapper but wouldn't the wrapper start to look like a manager?

Why restrict it to a file? It could be stored in a database or a file accessed over the internet; think resource.

Does this feel like something you want to wrap up? Extending the "Config" to a "FileConfig" makes more sense than wrapping it up.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do with it.

Wrapper class allows you to add some extra functionality, restrict some futures or change them... but if you think that nothing like that can ever happen and you will only use these getters/setters, it can be a little overkill and simple manager class is good enough.